# Prevent buttons from blinking in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, button

I've created a WPF application. This has to have a red colored theme. So I set every color to a type of red, but the problem is all the buttons within the window start blinking when the window opens. The funny thing is they start all simultaneously but after a while they begin to diverge. When the form loses focus they all stop blinking. When a button is clicked, only that one keeps blinking. But when a "not button" control gains focus they all start blinking again.

---

I found that it could have to do something with the Focusable property, but changing it doesn't change anything. I also found a way to overwrite the default style but that doesn't solve the problem ether. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5208927/1237495)

This is my XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="gServerSettings">
    <Label x:Name="lTitle" Content="Server Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="182,0,0,166" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="118" Foreground="#FFFF9999" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Height="34"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tServer" Margin="72,39,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFF9999" BorderBrush="#FFFF9999" SelectionBrush="#FFFF9999" BorderThickness="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="0"/>
    <Label x:Name="lServer" Content="Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Foreground="#FFFF9999" Height="24" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tDatabase" Margin="72,68,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFF9999" BorderBrush="#FFFF9999" SelectionBrush="#FFFF9999" BorderThickness="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="1"/>
    <Label x:Name="lDatabase" Content="Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Foreground="#FFFF9999" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="24"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tUsername" Margin="72,97,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFF9999" BorderBrush="#FFFF9999" SelectionBrush="#FFFF9999" BorderThickness="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="2"/>
    <Label x:Name="lUsername" Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Foreground="#FFFF9999" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="24"/>
    <Label x:Name="lPassword" Content="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Foreground="#FFFF9999" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="24"/>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="tPassword" Margin="72,126,10,0" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFF9999" BorderBrush="#FFFF9999" SelectionBrush="#FFFF9999" BorderThickness="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="3"/>
    <Button x:Name="bOK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFF9999" BorderThickness="1" IsDefault="True" TabIndex="6"/>
    <Button x:Name="bCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFF9999" BorderThickness="1" IsDefault="True" TabIndex="5"/>
    <Button x:Name="bTestConnection" Content="Test Connection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFF9999" BorderThickness="1" IsDefault="True" TabIndex="4" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```

I don't do anything programmatically yet, so my .CS file is empty.

[image: Normal]
[image: Blinking]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: They start blinking without any interaction from the user? Or only after they have been clicked?

Comment: They start blinking without any interaction. When the window or a "not button" control has focus they al start blinking. See my edits within the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to basically reimplement the button style and remove that storyboard. You can dump out the default button style with Expression Blend and modify it to your liking. There isn't really any other easy way to disable that storyboard.